# Using particle effects or animated sks files to create filled letters

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have one .png image of a single star. I'd like to use this image to create animated star-filled letters. This is what I'd like to do (but the stars would be sort of animated within this, which I imagine can be done with particle effects):

[image]

Could I do this by using potentially several sks files for each letter and then loading them into one larger scene? In addition, if I just wanted to fill the label node with a static texture of several stars, is there an alternate way of doing this?

Comment: You are asking for a really advanced thing here. This question is not really in line with how SO works so I am voting to close it as it is not a specific question that could yield a specific answer.  Some tips I can give you though is you can use CGPath to layout the design of how your sprites move, and you can use SKShader to help achieve the glowing effect around your stars

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thanks for the tips. I thought it was fairly specific as I refer to a method of doing it, and I'm trying to determine how to see that through. Perhaps I should edit to reflect that I'm thinking of trying to create a separate animation scene for each letter and then loading those letters in without using the labelNode? EDITED: I edited above.

Comment: If you can show code as to what you have attempted and can show a specific need to tweaking, that could work, but if you are asking a question that could yield a lot of possible answers, then it gets classified as too "broad".   Like in this case, some answers may be to use libraries X / Y, while others like me would say to get a CGPath off of a font.  I like using the CGPath approach because you can use an SKAction to have the stars move along the path, and the SKShader would be a simple glowing type shader that I am sure you could find online somewhere

Comment: @Knight0fDragon OK, that's fair enough. I'll give it a try and come back w/ a more specific question if I have one. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not ideal, but an easy to achieve:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        if let nodeToMask = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "firelfies") {

            backgroundColor = .black
            let cropNode = SKCropNode()
            cropNode.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
            cropNode.zPosition = 1

            let mask = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ArialMT")
            mask.text = "MASK"
            mask.fontColor = .green
            mask.fontSize = 185

            cropNode.maskNode = mask

            nodeToMask.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            nodeToMask.name = "character"
            cropNode.addChild(nodeToMask)

            addChild(cropNode)
        }  
    }
```

I think the code is self-explanatory, but basically, you just use text as a mask of a crop node, and you mask an emitter. Here is the result:

[image]

The thing with this implementation is that sparkles don't go outside of the letter bounds.

Comment: Why is this not ideal? Looks fine to me. Is it inefficient... or?

Comment: Because the particles doesn't go out of the bounds of a bounds of mask (text). But that is up to you. If you are satisfied with this effect, then just tweak an emitter and see what it can offer you.

Comment: About performance... I think it is performant as it can be. Particles are lightweight in compare to nodes. Of course test and see how far you can go.